# PHP function to build query string from array - not http build query

Tags: php

Hello I know all about http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php to do this however I have a little problem.

It "handly" turns boolean values into ones and zeros for me. I am building a little PHP wrapper for the Stack Overflow api and parsing an option array and then sending this onto the api breaks things..(doesn't like 1 for true).

What I would like is a simple function to turn a single dimensional array into a query string but turning true/false into string values of true/false.

Anyone know of anything that can do this before I start re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of anything offhand.  What I'd recommend is first iterating through the array and covert booleans to strings, then call `http_build_query`

E.g.

```
foreach($options_array as $key=>$value) :
    if(is_bool($value) ){
        $options_array[$key] = ($value) ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
endforeach;
$options_string=http_build_query($options_array);
```

Comment: Doh yes of course. Being an idiot...long day. Going to turn the computer off now.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing http_build_query true and false as strings instead of booleans. You may get different results.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to convert your `true`/`false` to `"true"`/`"false"`:

```
function aw_tostring (&$value,&$key) {
  if ($value === true) {
    $value = 'true';
  }
  else if ($value === false) {
    $value = 'false';
  }
}

array_walk($http_query,'aw_tostring');

// ... follow with your http_build_query() call
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each variable of the query string ($qs) and if bool true or false, then change value to string.

```
foreach($qs as $key=>$q) {
    if($q === true) $qs[$key] = 'true';
    elseif($q === false) $qs[$key] = 'false';
}
```

Then you can use the `http_build_query()`

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my wheel:

```
function buildSoQuery(array $array) {
    $parts = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $parts[] = urlencode($key).'='.(is_bool($value)?($value?'true':'false'):urlencode($value));
    }
    return implode('&', $parts);
}
```