# Remove parameter from link

Tags: php, regex

I have many links with parameter **number** - value is numbers between 1-1000

```
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=2
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&four=4&number=124
http://mysite.com?one=2&three=4&number=9
http://mysite.com?two=4&number=242
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=52
```

How can i  remove from this parameter and value with PHP? I would like receive:

```
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&four=4
http://mysite.com?one=2&three=4
http://mysite.com?two=4
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4
```

Comment: are you retrieving these links from database?

Comment: show me your code, wht have u tried so far.

Comment: how do you generate those URLs?

Comment: Use Hidden field to Get the `number` parameter on second page,its a rough suggestion,provide code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
$urls = '
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=2
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&four=4&number=124
http://mysite.com?one=2&three=4&number=9
http://mysite.com?two=4&number=242
http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=52
';

echo '<pre>';
echo preg_replace('#&number=\d+#', '', $urls);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$str    = 'http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=2';
$url    = parse_url($str);
parse_str($url['query'], $now );
unset($now['number']);
foreach($now as $key=>$value) :
    if(is_bool($value) ){
        $now[$key] = ($value) ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
endforeach;
$options_string=http_build_query($now);
echo $url    = 'http://mysite.com?'.$options_string;
```

Reference : [PHP function to build query string from array - not http build query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181822/php-function-to-build-query-string-from-array-not-http-build-query)

Answer (score 1):

If "&number=" is ALWAYS after the important parameters, I'd use str_split (or explode).
The more sure way is to use `parse_url()`,`parse_str()` and `http_build_query()` to break the URLs down and put them back together.

Answer (score 1):

you can build a redirection after building a new URL with $_GET['one']

Answer (score 1):

You could use [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) which parses the string into variables. In that way you can separate them easily

I wrote example of code.

```
<?php
 $arr = array();
 $arr[] = 'http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=2';
 $arr[] = 'http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&four=4&number=124';
 $arr[] = 'http://mysite.com?one=2&three=4&number=9';
 $arr[] = 'http://mysite.com?two=4&number=242';
 $arr[] = 'http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=52';

 function remove_invalid_arguments(array $array_invalid, $urlString)
 {
   $info = array();
   parse_str($urlString, $info);
   foreach($array_invalid as $inv)
  if(array_key_exists($inv,$info)) unset($info[$inv]);

   $ret = "";
   $i = 0;
   foreach($info as $k=>$v)
  $ret .= ($i++ ? "&" : ""). "$k=$v"; //maybe urlencode also :)

   return $ret;
 }

 //usage
 $invalid = array('number'); //array of forbidden params
 foreach($arr as $k=>&$v) $v =remove_invalid_arguments($invalid, $arr[1]);

 print_r($arr);

?>
```

[Working DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/97k-vfn)

Answer (score 1):

Use bellow steps,this is clear aproach

```
1- Parse the url into an array with parse_url()
2-  Extract the query portion, decompose that into an array
3- Delete the query parameters you want by unset() them from the array
4- Rebuild the original url using http_build_query()
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

As per example of your url -

```
 $s='http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=2&number2=200';
 $temp =explode('&',$s);
 array_pop($temp);
 echo $newurl = implode("&", $last);
```

Output is :http://mysite.com?one=2&two=4&number=2

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one using regex: (as an alternative, preferably use a parser)

```
(.+?)(?:&number=\d+)
```

Assuming `&number=2` is the last parameter. This regex will keep the whole url except the last parameter `number`