# Build query string with indexed array data

Tags: php, arrays

I pass my function an object that contains some answers.  I then do the following to create an associative array

```
$field_data = array();
foreach($submission->answers as $answer) {
    $field_data[$answer->question_id] = $answer->text + 1;
}
```

This results in array like so

```
array:15 [▼
  1 => 3
  2 => 4
  3 => 2
  4 => 5
]
```

What I need to do is build an API call using the above data.  The API URL would look something like this

> someAPI.com?api.php?function=calculatePrice&question**1**=**3**&question2=4&question3=2&question4=5

Where the question number is the value on the left side of the array, and the part after the = sign is the value on the right of the array.

What would be the best way to create this URL using the array I have?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to build query string from array - not http build query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181822/php-function-to-build-query-string-from-array-not-http-build-query)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [http-build-query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) method itself of php. The second param accepts the prefix to prepend to the key.
**The key should be of numeric type**

You can use the `http-build-query` like this in your case

```
http_build_query($field_data, 'question');
```